# Pandas combine row element in one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe that is populated by an CSV, and after that I read the columns and iterate by element in row (for each element in column) and writes that element in a file. My problem is that I have elements in row that I want joined into one element.

Say I have A through Z columns, and let's say it's elements are 1 to 23. Let's say that I want joined the number 9 and 10 (columns I and J) in one element only (columns I and J become one and it's values become[9,10])

How do I achieve that using pandas (while iterating)?

My code is long but you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/QFkz4VwC). I've tried [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) but I think it only work with booleans and int (correct me if I'm wrong)

Also I'm pretty new to Python, any advises on my code would be much apreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. It adds a new column where each entry is the list of two other columns. I hope it helps!

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4))
df[4]= [[df[2][x],df[3][x]] for x in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Comment: If you format (especially [`code`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) your answer, it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the columns, then convert to a list using numpy's `tolist()`:

```
In [56]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,1,1], I=[9,9,9], J=[10,10,10]))

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
   A  I   J
0  1  9  10
1  1  9  10
2  1  9  10

In [58]: df["IJ"] = pd.concat((df.I, df.J), axis=1).values.tolist()

In [59]: df.drop(["I","J"], axis=1)
Out[59]:
   A       IJ
0  1  [9, 10]
1  1  [9, 10]
2  1  [9, 10]
```